# How can I copy a file with a BATCH script from a folder on one drive to a folder of the same name on another drive?

Tags: batch-file, variables, copy

I'd like to make a Batch script to copy hundreds of files to their proper directories. Having to do this several times I figured a script would be helpful in the future. The only problem is I don't know the filenames or the directories they're in, ok I mean I do, but there's hundreds of them so it's not going to help.

Basically, I have the images for the movies in `c:\movies` in their own folders, but the movies are all in `f:\movies` in folders of the same name for each movie. I want to get the images and the movies all together again.

Example:

```
copy c:\movies\%dir%\%img%.png F:\Movies\%dir%\%img%.png
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be made more dynamic, but your requirement is pretty simple.

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:d "c:\movies"') do (
 copy /Y "C:\movies\%%a\*.png" "F:\movies\%%a"
)
```